# Scraping Website With Infinite Scroll Using Scrapy

Tags: javascript, json, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape used items in my area from https://us.letgo.com/en for a personal project.  I found this video helpful https://youtu.be/EelmnSzykyI. However, there are some subtle differences that the video doesn't help with.

The info I need is loaded asyncrhonously via json.  The website loads 15 items per each scroll (except for the initial load which contains 30 items).  The json object looks like this: https://search-products-pwa.letgo.com/api/products?country_code=US&offset=0&quadkey=0320030123201&num_results=30&distance_type=mi and the next 15 items to load look like this: https://search-products-pwa.letgo.com/api/products?country_code=US&offset=30&quadkey=0320030123201&num_results=15&distance_type=mi

When I load the first response `data = json.loads(response.text)` it returns a list of the 30 items.  The first item looks like this:

```
{'attributes': None,
 'category_id': 5,
 'created_at': '2018-02-12T15:40:56+00:00',
 'currency': 'USD',
 'description': None,
 'featured': False,
 'geo': {'city': 'Asheville',
  'country_code': 'US',
  'distance': 1.1703344331099,
  'lat': 35.5889898,
  'lng': -82.5308015,
  'zip_code': '28805'},
 'id': '6080a1db-b2af-44c2-bfd8-4cc7f1ded17f',
 'image_information': 'brown ukulele',
 'images': [{'id': 'b8e78e2e-65c4-4062-b89e-c775ef9f6bc9',
   'url': 'https://img.letgo.com/images/ab/da/e2/f6/abdae2f68e34170d8f1f22d2473d1153.jpeg'}],
 'language_code': 'US',
 'name': None,
 'owner': {'avatar_url': '',
  'banned': False,
  'city': 'Asheville',
  'country_code': 'US',
  'id': 'fb0f8657-0273-4fac-ba77-9965a1dc8794',
  'is_richy': False,
  'name': 'Brock G',
  'status': 'active',
  'zip_code': '28805'},
 'price': 100,
 'price_flag': 2,
 'rejected': False,
 'status': 1,
 'thumb': {'height': 1280,
  'url': 'https://img.letgo.com/images/ab/da/e2/f6/abdae2f68e34170d8f1f22d2473d1153.jpeg?impolicy=img_200',
  'width': 960},
 'updated_at': '2018-02-12T15:41:34+00:00'}
```

My aim is to create a for loop and extract out each item and then move on to the next request that loads in an additional 15 items but I'm not sure how to do this.  Please note that the additional request parameters are as follows:
[image]

[image]

*Update*

I am getting close but can't seem to figure out how I can simply update the offset parameter within the function that is essentially recursively calling itself:

```
class LetgoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'letgo'
    allowed_domains = ['letgo.com/en']
    start_urls = ['https://search-products-pwa.letgo.com/api/products?country_code=US&offset=0&quadkey=0320030123201&num_results=50&distance_type=mi']

    def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        for used_item in data:
            if len(data) == 0:
                break
            try:
                title = used_item['name']
                price = used_item['price']
                description = used_item['description']
                date = used_item['updated_at']
                images = [img['url'] for img in used_item['images']]
                latitude = used_item['geo']['lat']
                longitude = used_item['geo']['lng']               
            except Exception:
                pass

        yield {'Title': title,
               'Price': price,
               'Description': description,
               'Date': date,
               'Images': images,
               'Latitude': latitude,
               'Longitude': longitude          
               }    

        i = 0
        for new_items_load in response:
            i += 50 
            offset = i
            new_request = 'https://search-products-pwa.letgo.com/api/products?country_code=US&offset=' + str(i) + \
                          '&quadkey=0320030123201&num_results=50&distance_type=mi'
            yield scrapy.Request(new_request, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand well your question.

If you just need to know how to define the parameters, this could be a way:

```
  let offset, num_results;
  for(let i = 0; i < max; i += 15) {
    offset = i;
    num_results = i + 15;
    [do the request with the parameters values]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I just need to continue to update the request to move on to the next 15 items after I load and scrape the current items.  I'm not sure how to stop the requests or account for when there are no more items left to scrape either.  I'm fairly new to python and scrapy still..

Comment: `class LetgoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'letgo'
    allowed_domains = ['letgo.com/en']
    start_urls = ['https://search-products-pwa.letgo.com/api/products?country_code=US&offset=0&quadkey=0320030123201&num_results=30&distance_type=mi']

    def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(resonse.text)
        for used_item in data:
            yield {
                
            }`

Comment: ok, there are two options, one is to try to reach out one of the ending pages. The final page can return an empty list, an error...
Once you identify the difference, you will be able to add this condition to the bucle to end it.

Comment: In addition, some cases have an attribute in all responses specifying the total length, are this responses only returning you the item list as array? or some additional attributes?

Comment: The best way to find a ending page id to search some case with few element, for example if the pagination is increasing +15, find some case that you can see in the browser that will be only two or three pages (<30 or <45).
You can see the response in the console too.

Comment: It appears that I can max out the num_results parameter to 50.  I will just need to figure out how to continue to update the offset parameter and num_result parameter until I go through all the items.  Maybe I should add an if statement that specifies if num_results is less than 50, load that last batch of items and then stop?

Comment: Hi Keenan, Iv'e took a look to the web and finally the last respone is an empty list
`[]`
So you just have to add a condition to check if the list.length is 0.
Do not do the condition based on < 50 or other number because the call before the end one could have from 1 to X items, for example for my search there was exactly 33 results so the call before the empty response one,  had a size of 3, and you don't want to loose these 3 items ;)

Comment: Take a look at my update if you can and let me know your thoughts.  I'm still struggling to finish the code so the function works properly.  See the for loop at the end, it needs a revision but I can't wrap my head around how I should do this properly.

Comment: I'm not used to python, but I think you are doing the logic wrong. 
Just try to do a unique parent loop including the first call, and once there are a call with 0 length, go out of the loop (boolean var). For example a while loop would be good, think that the breaks sentences only works for the closest loops, you need to stop the parent loop.
I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks!  I figured it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48757828/update-parameter-for-web-scraping-with-infinite-scroll/48758010#48758010

Comment: You're welcome! Please give me a vote if I've been helpful somehow :)