# Update Parameter for Web Scraping With Infinite Scroll

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am unsure how I should structure my code here so that the offset parameter updates each time the function recursively calls itself.  Here is more detail about my script and the challenge I'm trying to solve.  I feel like there is some easy fix that I'm missing here.  [Scraping Website With Infinite Scroll Using Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48751029/scraping-website-with-infinite-scroll-using-scrapy)

```
import scrapy
import json
import requests

class LetgoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'letgo'
    allowed_domains = ['letgo.com/en']
    start_urls = ['https://search-products-pwa.letgo.com/api/products?country_code=US&offset=0&quadkey=0320030123201&num_results=50&distance_type=mi']

    def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        for used_item in data:
            if len(data) == 0:
                break
            try:
                title = used_item['name']
                price = used_item['price']
                description = used_item['description']
                date = used_item['updated_at']
                images = [img['url'] for img in used_item['images']]
                latitude = used_item['geo']['lat']
                longitude = used_item['geo']['lng']               
            except Exception:
                pass

        yield {'Title': title,
               'Price': price,
               'Description': description,
               'Date': date,
               'Images': images,
               'Latitude': latitude,
               'Longitude': longitude          
               }    

        i = 0
        for new_items_load in response:
            i += 50 
            offset = i
            new_request = 'https://search-products-pwa.letgo.com/api/products?country_code=US&offset=' + str(i) + \
                          '&quadkey=0320030123201&num_results=50&distance_type=mi'
            yield scrapy.Request(new_request, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define offset as a class attribute:

```
class LetgoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'letgo'
    allowed_domains = ['letgo.com/en']
    start_urls = ['https://search-products-pwa.letgo.com/api/products?country_code=US&offset=0&quadkey=0320030123201&num_results=50&distance_type=mi']
    offset = 0  # <- here
```

Then, you can refer to it using `self.offset` and the value will be shared across all function `parse` invokes. So it'd be something like this:

```
self.offset += 50
new_request = 'https://search-products-pwa.letgo.com/api/products?country_code=US&offset=' + str(self.offset) + \
                      '&quadkey=0320030123201&num_results=50&distance_type=mi'
yield scrapy.Request(new_request, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I followed your instructions but for some reason I'm getting NameError: name 'offset' is not defined when I run `scrapy crawl letgo -o test.json` . I double checked and didnt make a typo either.  Any idea why it wouldn't be defined?  It may be because this Scrapy class is a default class it provides as a template when you create a new spider?

Comment: Sorry, try again. It should have been `self.offset` in the new_request creation. I've just edited the code.

Comment: Thanks.  Getting closer..its saying that the scrape properly worked however it only scrapes the first item. I think it may have something to do with `if len(data) == 0:
                break`

Comment: Try to debug it by adding several prints. Just to understand what it is doing: how many times `parse` has been called? How many objects has it got? etc. One thing I see at the first glance is that `yield {...}` should be inside the for loop (not after it).

Comment: Whoops! That just fixed the scraping one item issue and it took care of the first 50.  However it didn't continue on to the next batch of items so I must still be missing something related to making the new request with the updated offset parameter.

Comment: I think I need to include this adjusted domain to my allowed domains to make it work..we'll see  `https://search-products-pwa.letgo.com/api/products?country_code=US&offset=50&quadkey=0320030123201&num_results=50&distance_type=mi
2018-02-12 20:51:42 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'search-products-pwa.letgo.com': <GET https://search-products-pwa.letgo.com/api/products?country_code=US&offset=50&quadkey=0320030123201&num_results=50&distance_type=mi>`

Comment: Yup, adjusted `allowed_domains = ['letgo.com/en', 'search-products-pwa.letgo.com']` and it works now